# continuous getting shake signal in android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, shake, sensormanager

I created one class for shake detection and one for shake service to act when shake is detected. When I run the service, I m continuously shake signal. Can some one guide where is the issue.

Shake Service as below:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

/**
 * Created by DELL WORLD on 5/31/2017.
 */

public class ShakeService extends Service {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        System.out.println("Shake Service Started");
        // ShakeDetector initialization
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mAccelerometer = mSensorManager
                .getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        mShakeDetector = new ShakeDetector();
        mShakeDetector.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeDetector.OnShakeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onShake(int count) {
                System.out.println("Shaken");



            }
        });
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mShakeDetector, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mShakeDetector);
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("Shake Service Destroyed");
    }
}
```

and shake detector as below:

```
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.util.FloatMath;

/**
 * Created by DELL WORLD on 5/5/2017.
 */

public class ShakeDetector implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private ShakeDetector mShakeDetector;
    /*
  * The gForce that is necessary to register as shake.
  * Must be greater than 1G (one earth gravity unit).
  * You can install "G-Force", by Blake La Pierre
  * from the Google Play Store and run it to see how
  *  many G's it takes to register a shake
  */
    private static final float SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY = 2.7F;
    private static final int SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS = 500;
    private static final int SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS = 3000;

    private OnShakeListener mListener;
    private long mShakeTimestamp;
    private int mShakeCount;

    public void setOnShakeListener(OnShakeListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnShakeListener {
        public void onShake(int count);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // ignore
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        if (mListener != null) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];

            float gX = x / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gY = y / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
            float gZ = z / SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;

            // gForce will be close to 1 when there is no movement.
            //float gForce = FloatMath.sqrt(gX * gX + gY * gY + gZ * gZ);
            float gForce = Math.abs(x + y + z - gX - gY - gZ);
            if (gForce > SHAKE_THRESHOLD_GRAVITY) {
                final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                // ignore shake events too close to each other (500ms)
                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_SLOP_TIME_MS > now) {
                    return;
                }

                // reset the shake count after 3 seconds of no shakes
                if (mShakeTimestamp + SHAKE_COUNT_RESET_TIME_MS < now) {
                    mShakeCount = 0;
                }

                mShakeTimestamp = now;
                mShakeCount++;

                mListener.onShake(mShakeCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked many links but not got suitable solution. gForce value is coming around 8.32 when mobile is stable and lying on table untouched.

Answer (score 0):

i complied with  to complete shake detector coding. It is code with flawless java files for shake detector.

compile 'com.github.safetysystemtechnology:android-shake-detector:v1.2'